# How to get the second element by matching text from the first element. In Selenium, Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, element

HTML Snippet for reference:

```
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gridTD">TITLE</td>
    <td class="gridTD">NAME</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
```

There are a series of **tr** elements whose position changes, so I have to find the specific one from text within the **td** sub-elements.
I'm trying to grab the *second* **td** element with the NAME information by matching the text from the *first* **td** element but I don't know how to access it.

I am new to Selenium and just getting into using xpaths to locate elements.

These return the first element just fine:

```
n = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divDistrictContacts']/table/tbody//tr//*[text()='TITLE]")

n = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divDistrictContacts']/table/tbody//tr/td[text()='TITLE]")
```

but I don't know where to go from here. I've tried looking it up but can't seem to find how to grab the second element specifically from matching text from the first element.

I've tried adding [position() = 2] and [2] in variations after [text()='TITLE'] and changing the // and * in the xpath, and I either get "no such element" or invalid xpaths.

If this is at all helpful, this is the full xpath (I replaced the tr index with i since it is an unreliable value):

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[i]/td[2]
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? what is the end goal?

Comment: Maybe first use `TITLE` to get `tr` - like `//tr[td[text()="TITLE"]]` - and later get second `td` in this `tr`  -  `(//tr[td[text()="TITLE"]]//td)[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nested one `[ ]` inside another `[ ]`

Maybe first use `TITLE` to get `tr` - `//tr[td[text()="TITLE"]]`

And later get second `td` in this `tr` - `(//tr[td[text()="TITLE"]]//td)[2]`

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use `following-sibling`

```xml
//td[text()="TITLE"]/following-sibling::td
```

---

Full working example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

html = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="gridTD">TITLE</td>
    <td class="gridTD">NAME</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
'''

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//tr[td[text()="TITLE"]]//td)[2]')
print(item.text)

item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[text()="TITLE"]/following-sibling::td')
print(item.text)
```

Comment: Always  better solution along with great explanation

Comment: WOW, I have not run across "following-sibiling::element" yet so it was the first one I tried and it worked, thank you so much! I have been sifting through so many forums and how-to's. How exciting to finally be able to move on from this problem! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `following-sibling`

```xml
//td[text()='TITLE']//following-sibling::td
```

http://xpather.com/ Example:
[image]